# How to replace all characters in a set in the beginning of a line?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have lines like these:

```
,,,,,,,,,foo,bar
,,,,,x,,blabla,
```

With *regex*, is it possible to replace only the *commas* in the beginning of the lines by the same number of *spaces* and if yes, how?

Comment: perl or sed in this case, but with a language I could figure it out. I just wanted to know if there is a pure regex-based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java, with a positive lookbehind:

```
String s = ",,,,,,,,,foo,bar";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=^,+),", " "));
// '         foo,bar'
```

Using Python:

```
> import re
> s = ',,,,,,,,,foo,bar'
> re.sub("^,+", lambda m: len(m.group(0)) * ' ', s)
'         foo,bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

`sed` example:

```
$ echo ',,,,,,,,,foo,bar
,,,,,x,,blabla,' | sed ':r;s/^\(,*\),/\1 /;tr'
         foo,bar
     x,,blabla,
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^,+/q{ } x length $&/e' <<< ',,,,,,,,,foo,bar'
```